# Show $\operatorname{Re} z$ and $\operatorname{Im} z$ are not complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Approach a)

$$\lim_{\Delta{z}\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z+\Delta{z})-\operatorname{Re}(z)}{\Delta{x}+\Delta{y}i}$$ 
Let $z=x+yi$ and $\Delta{z}=\Delta{x}+\Delta{y}i$

$$\lim_{\Delta{z}\rightarrow0}\frac{\operatorname{Re}((x+\Delta{x})+i(y+\Delta{y}))-\operatorname{Re}(x+yi)}{\Delta{x}+\Delta{y}i} =\lim_{\Delta{z}\rightarrow0}\frac{x+\Delta{x}-x}{\Delta{x}+\Delta{y}i} = \lim_{\Delta{z}\rightarrow0}\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{x}+\Delta{y}i}.$$

If we approach $\Delta{z}$ from the real axis the we would get $$\lim_{\Delta{x}\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{x}}=1.$$

If we approach $\Delta{z}$ from the imaginary axis, we get

$$\lim_{\Delta{y}\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{\Delta{yi}}.$$

I don't know if I am doing this right and I don't know how to handle the last issue

They way the book does it is by approaching different points from the real and imaginary to get different results.

Comment: Can't you just do it for the real case but set $Im(z) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, the notation is alittle bit confusing. Does the following make sense? $\lim_{(\Delta{x},0)\rightarrow 0}=\frac{\Delta{x}}{\Delta{x}}=1$

Comment: @TheMathNoob: You want to keep $\Delta z$ arbitrary, in which case the denominator will be $\Delta z$ not $\Delta x$.

Comment: Why don't you point out your specific confusion in this post?  It's going to be difficult to provide a satisfactory answer without a question.

Comment: You have the limit of no expression at all equal to a difference quotient.

Comment: What exactly is the question now? You were asking about $f$ and $f'$ before.

Comment: I am gonna post my solution and my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. As for the last limit, note that for $\Delta y \neq 0$,

$$\frac{0}{\Delta yi} = 0$$

so

$$\lim_{\Delta y \to 0}\frac{0}{\Delta y i} = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} 0 = 0.$$

As the limits along the real and imaginary axes are different, the original limit does not exist, therefore, $\operatorname{Re}z$ is not complex differentiable.

You can prove that $\operatorname{Im}z$ is not complex differentiable in exactly the same way.